# Cloning usercontrol using Jquery

Tags: asp.net

Page contains four grid with same no of columns.so, i have created a usercontrol which i am dragging four times on my page so it has created. `uc1:grid1,uc1:grid2,uc1:grid3,uc1:grid4`.

This means after rendering it will fetch four grids from the server. So If i create a grid & using Jquery .clone() i.e `$(grid).clone()` If i create 3 clones I can reduce server overhead. Is there any problem using this method?

Comment: But all grids have different data and columns, right?

Comment: no i am managing everything clientside

Comment: Then how this is connected to asp.net/usercontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after cloning you need other data manipulation like changing headers and CSS and stuff like that, then sticking to your server code is more reasonable. But if you have 4 **identical** grids, int both **structure** and **data**, and they all have the same styles, then choose `clone()` method.